# How to find a closed thread by id in Discord JS?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelID);
if (channel) {    
                const membersList = await channel.members.fetch()
                if (!membersList.has(newMember.id)) {
                    channel.send(`${newMember.user} adding you here :3`);
                } else {
                    console.log('User already in the threadList!')
                }             
}
```

Essentially, the problem is: If thread is closed manually in discord app, channel=undefined, if thread is opened code works.
Is there a chance that closed thread is not archived or they stored somewhere else(not in client.channels.cache)?
I need to open it if it closed, but can't find it by id when it's closed.

Essentially, the problem is: If thread is closed manually in discord app, channel=undefined, if thread is opened code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fetch archived threads

```
let parentChannel = client.channels.cache.get('PARENT CHANNEL ID HERE');

let channel;
await parentChannel.threads.fetchArchived().then(() => {
    channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelID);
})
```

If the thread you are trying to find is a private thread, use

```
[...].threads.fetchArchived({ type: 'private', fetchAll: true })[...]
```

Sources:

[How do i get archived threads from id in discord.js?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Discord_Bots/comments/u9ykcm/how_do_i_get_archived_threads_from_id_in_discordjs/)

[discordjs documentation](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/14.11.0/class/GuildForumThreadManager?scrollTo=fetchArchived)